# Write a logical expression for the $NOT (x)$ function that uses only the $NAND$ operator

Tags: logic

Write a logical expression for the $NOT (x)$ function that uses only the $NAND$ operator; repeat the exercise also for the functions $OR (x, y)$ and $AND (x, y)$.

I'm not sure if my solutions are correct. For the first one I wrote $\overline{xx}$, for the second one I wrote $\overline{\bar{x}\bar{y}}$ but I don't know how to write the last one.

Comment: Hint: It is *not* a surprise that $NOT(AND (x, y)) = NAND(x,y)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)NOT(x) = $\overline{xx}$ is correct

2)For the OR(x), saying that OR(x,y)=$\overline{\bar{x}\bar{y}}$ is not enough, because you give the impressions that you're directly using NOT gates on x and y. Instead, make use of NOT area from the first part, I.e.

OR(x,y)=$\overline{NOT(x)NOT(y)} = \overline{\overline{xx}\,\overline{yy}}$

3)As for AND(x,y) = NOT(NAND(x,y)). Again, you can use the NOT gate from the first part 1 and say

AND(x,y) = NOT(NAND(x,y)) = $\overline{\overline{xy}}$